# How to find chrome driver version in use for a node on a Selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Is there a way to check the chrome driver version in use on a particular node remotely?

I know running `chromedriver.exe -v` directly on the node will report the driver version. But is there any way to query this through the selenium grid api?

I've looked at the useful information here but I can't see a way to do it: https://github.com/nicegraham/selenium-grid2-api

Or ideally I'd like to see this displayed on configuration tab of the selenium grid console for each node.

Maybe there's a way to display this as an extra property I add to the configuration by capturing the output of running `capture the output of chromedriver.exe -v` prior to connecting the node to the grid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a configuration file for your node you can add the currently running/deployed chromedriver version to that and than it will be shown in the Configuration tab.
I added the chromedriver version by hand, but you can easily add this during deployment of the node.

[image: Configuration file with capabilities]

This way it will be displayed in the capabilities section of the Configuration tab in your /grid/console.

[image: Capabilities with chromedriver version]

PS: If you need the Chromedriver version during runtime of your code you can get it with `driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("chrome")` and than parse the `chromedriverVersion` with a RegEx.

Comment: Using Protractor (Angular) I had to use:

let cap = browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(c => c.get("chrome"));

console.log(await cap);